# Magrittr functions - how to package them?

Tags: r, function, magrittr

I have two related questions about writing functions in `magrittr` package & including them in a package.

In normal way of writing a function, you can specify `library(package.a)` within function call if any of the steps uses a function from `package.a`. How would you call this in `pipe` environment (from `magrittr`)?

This part of the question arose when I tried to package my functions, and a few of my functions use `magrittr`'s way of creating functions. I wasn't able to add those functions to package. `Devtools` package's `combine` function didn't recognize `%>%` pipe. Basically I had to re-write them to normal functions to include them in the package. How do you overcome this?

Comment: Post your `NAMESPACE` file. If the package is not just a homework and you are going to maintain it over time I recommend to read [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html), this is a great document for any pkg dev.

Comment: exportPattern("^[^\\.]")

Comment: Update your `NAMESPACE` file, see [1.5 Package namespaces](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces). Add `import(magrittr)`, don't forget to add `Imports: magrittr` in `DESCRIPTION` file.

Comment: @jangorecki, Thank you for your reply. Yeah it solves the problem I asked in 2nd question. I think I can use  `package.a::function.do.that` to call for a function from a package within a function I create.  How do I make your comment as 'answer`?

Comment: there are two camps regarding using pipes within package. one suggests not to since - when errors occur - debugging is more difficult. 6/1 | 0.5*12 but it might be good to test boundary & error conditions to ensure you won't confuse users (or your future self ;-). If your example or desired functionality by users of package is to invoke `%>%` then you should also re-export it from your package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your `NAMESPACE` file, see [1.5 Package namespaces](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces).
Add `import(magrittr)`, don't forget to add `Imports: magrittr` in `DESCRIPTION` file.

Regarding your comment on `::`.
While you are importing all magrittr exported function by using `import(magrittr)` you don't have to use `::` operator to point the package.
Of course as long as you did not create a function with the same name in your package which would override the name from imported package, then you do need `::`.
Also the `::` would be needed if you would used `importFrom()` instead of `import()` and you did not import required function - that might be not recommended anyway.
Another case where you may want to use `::` is when you use `Suggests` or `Enhances`, none of them is in scope of that question anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer. For my scenario, I went with `suggests: magrittr` in `Description` file and `importFrom(magrittr, "%>%")` in namespace. And everything worked amazingly!

Comment: @JeanVuda if you import something in NAMESPACE you should also import it in DESCRIPTION. Suggest should be used only for optional part of the code, like tests, vignettes, etc. Then instead of `importFrom` in NAMESPACE you can use `if(requireNamespace("pkg")) pkg::fun()` or `if(require("pkg")) fun()`. Having magrittr in suggest in DESCRIPTION will not install magrittr when installing your package, so code in your package will not work.